# How to write a filter to check for distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter

I have a very large table, part of which looks like this. In the 'Recipes' column are recipes used at two factories listed in the 'Site' column. I'm wanting to perform a check to see if either all recipes produced at site B are also produced at site A, or if site B has some 'distinct' recipes that only it uses.

| Recipe | Site |
| --- | --- |
| X001 | A |
| X001 | A |
| X002 | A |
| X002 | B |
| X002 | B |
| X003 | A |

Comment: What are your expected results for the given sample?

Comment: How large is 'very large' here? What's the row count

Comment: Use the EXCEPT operator. In pseudo-code: select rows for site B <except> select rows for site A (or all other sites - choose how flexible your logic should be).

Answer (score 0):

While not necessarily intuitive, **GROUP BY** does magics in scenarios like this.

**Here is a simple, direct answer to the question**

```
select     Recipe
        
from       t

group by   Recipe

having     count(case Site when 'B' then 1 end) > 0
       and count(case Site when 'A' then 1 end) = 0
```

**The following query will give you a detailed view**

```
select   Recipe
        ,max(case Site when 'A' then 'V' end) as A_exists
        ,max(case Site when 'B' then 'V' end) as B_exists
        ,count(*)                             as total_count
        ,count(case Site when 'A' then 1 end) as A_count
        ,count(case Site when 'B' then 1 end) as B_count
        
from     t

group by Recipe
```

**The following query will give you a summarized view**

```
with t2 as
(
    select   max(case Site when 'A' then 'V' end) as A_exists
            ,max(case Site when 'B' then 'V' end) as B_exists
        
    from     t

    group by Recipe
)
select      A_exists
           ,B_exists
           ,count(*) as total_Recipes

from        t2

group by    A_exists
           ,B_exists
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9167cce6b2561d436d03093e08e10e7e)
Please note that I added some rows to the sample in order to make it more interesting